# check if text file contain= exists file name

Tags: vb.net

hello i have a text file contain 3 lines filename1 filename2 filename3 i want to check if
one of them = exists file name my code work only if my text file contain just 1 line

```
        Dim address As String = ("http://localhost/file.txt")
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address))
    Dim line As String = reader.ReadToEnd
    If File.Exists(line) = True Then
        MsgBox("FOUND")
    End If
```

Comment: parse `line` into each file name, presumably split on NewLine or space depeding on how accurate your description is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:
First I download the text file to the system

Then I read each line of the text file and check if the file exists:

Make sure to import system.io

```
Imports System.IO
```

Add the following function:

```
 Public Function ReadALine(ByVal File_Path As String, ByVal Line2Read As Integer) As String
    Dim Buffer As Array
    Dim Line As String
    Buffer = File.ReadAllLines(File_Path)
    Line = Buffer(Line2Read)
    Return Line
End Function
```

Now let's assume you downloaded the text file to the C: directory

```
Dim filename As String = "C:\file.txt"
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(ReadALine(filename, 0)) Then
        MsgBox("FOUND")
    End If
```

Change the number 0 to 1 or to 2 to get the second and third lines

[Read a text file line by line - VB.NET](http://visual-basic-tutorials.com/1182010164621.php)